# How to extend vertically positioned `LinearProgressIndicator` to all available vertical space

Tags: flutter

I'm currently stuck with my layout experiments in Flutter.

A `LinearProgressIndicator` positioned vertically in a `RotatedBox` should extend as far as possible in the vertical direction.

The given code works, but the `LinearProgressIndicator` does not extend as far as possible in the vertical direction.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Vertical LinearProgressIndicator Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Left'),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Top'),
                RotatedBox(
                  quarterTurns: 3,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 300, // Should not be hard coded
                    height: 25,
                    child:
                        LinearProgressIndicator(), // Is supposed to extend as far as possible
                  ),
                ),
                Text('Bottom'),
              ],
            ),
            Text('Right'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the Rotated Box in a Expanded Widget like this

```
Expanded(
         child:
            RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: 3,
              child: 
                    LinearProgressIndicator(), 
     
         ))
```

Note the an Expanded Widget must be a child of a Row Widget or Column Widget
which will expand to the main axis of the parent element.

Here's a code pen

https://codepen.io/brocatz/pen/oNZVLPX

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It looks like I was already on the right track, but I wrapped the `LinearProgressIndicator` widget into an `Expanded` widget and this in turn into a `RotatedBox` widget.